# mounting docker for shared path

Tags: macos, docker, rancher

I am trying to mount a shared namespace

The export path /private/var/lib overlaps with the export path /private
despite the path I am looking giving is on /usr/lib/rancher

sudo docker run --rm --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher rancher/agent:v2.0-alpha4 http://0.0.0.0:8080/v3/scripts/123ABC:123ABC:foo

docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:
The path /var/lib/rancher
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
.
ERRO[0091] error waiting for container: context canceled

It happens with stable and tech preview installation of Rancher
How can I make this run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker for Mac is not supported and will not work right even if you get the docker VM registered as a host.  For example publishing ports doesn't work because the games docker plays to bind them to the Mac are not compatible with the way CNI drivers map ports with iptables.

Comment: Not supported by whom?

Comment: By Rancher, for use as a host for 1.x (or early 2.0 alpha, at the time here).  For recent 2.0 you can use the Kubernetes in Docker for Mac.